# How to maintain images when cancel button clicking even if deleted?

Tags: php, codeigniter, crud, grocery-crud

In grocery crud edit form there is cancel button for cancelling this edit options and will go to view form.

In edit form, image selection have image delete option.

[image]

But after delete button click, even if cancel button click the image will be deleted.

Anyone have any solution to resolve this ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So when you click the cancel button after you click the delete, the image is still deleted? If that's the case, it's because you've already sent and processed the request to delete the image. So even if you click cancel, the image has already been deleted.

One way around this is to include a save button. The delete request is not sent until the user clicks save. If the user clicks cancel, redirect them back to the view.

Comment: How we can implement this in grocery crud?